# High availability deactivating from ansible tower

Tags: ansible-tower

I installed the ansible tower trial version "Basic version".

When I create a project via the tower GUI interface and tried to run it, a problem appeared saying that the feature " ha " is not configured in this version.

Please, how can I disable the ha option from my trial version.

The code seem like this:

```
"
{
    "instances": {
        "primary": "192.168.122.158",
        "secondaries": [
            "192.168.122.109",
            "192.168.122.26"
        ]
    },
    "ha": true,
    "role": "primary",
    "version": "2.1.4"
}
"
```

I want the "ha": false.